# Submit a function programmatically even if a field is named "submit"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I need to write Javascript code that *always* submits a form. The first form I had to submit looked like this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/test">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Send data" name="submit">
</form>
```

(Imagine that `formNode` is `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]`)

So, `formNode.submit()` didn't work because 'submit' is basically taken by the "Send data" button (!).

I then thought that I should use the form's action (somebody could use `action` as a name too!).

I then thought about focussing on the first input field I could find, and simulating an ENTER keypress. But, my initial tests didn't work and decided to ask here before doing what I normally do (bang my head against the wall for hours).

So: What's a good, reliable way to submit *any* form *regardless* of how it's made, regardless of braindead names to fields, etc.?

Or, maybe: how do I get the form's `submit()` function reliably, regardless of fields given the same name, so that I can submit the thing?

Comment: I don't have control over the name of the fields.

Comment: It may work to inspect the *form.submit* property and if it's an element (say has a tagName property and a name property of *submit*), create a shallow clone of the form and copy across all the controls and re–name the *submit* control to something else before attaching it to the new form. Also set all the control values to the current value of their originals, then submit that form. This is likely not a general solution, but may work i some cases.

Comment: @RobG ouch, this hurts! I just found a _possible_ way: `form.__proto__.submit.call( form );`. Yes it only works in browsers with __proto__ but it seems reliable?

Comment: Well, that might be "reliable" except that the `__proto__` property is not standard, not supported in all browsers in use and not all browsers use a prototype inheritance model so there is no `Form.prototype` to reference. Also, host objects may not necessarily support built–in methods like that. I've posted an answer with possibly a better solution.

Comment: —it seems that calling submit via the prototype does not disptach a submit event, at least in IE 9, so any submit listeners (e.g. form validation) won't get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to first test if *form.submit* is a submit button and if it is, programmatically click it:

```
// Probably need better testing for whether it's a button or input or whatever
// this is just a proof of concept
if (form.submit && typeof form.submit.tagName == 'string' && form.submit.click) {
  form.submit.click();

} else {
  form.submit();
}
```

This appears to work in IE at least, however you'll need to test widely to determine support in other browsers. You may need to dispatch a click event on the button (using both IE and W3C models for dispatching events), or use other methods for those that don't support the *click* method.

Another approach is to add a submit button and click it:

```
<form id="f0">
  <input name="foo" value="foo">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<button onclick="
  var form = document.forms.f0;
  var button = document.createElement('input');
  button.type = 'submit';
  button.value = 'submit button';
  form.appendChild(button);
  button.click();
">Add submit button and click it</button>
```

Users should never see the button as browsers generally wont update the UI until a function has finished. By that time the form should have been submitted, so again no UI update.

This should also cause a submit event to be dispatched, so submit listeners should be called. It may be best to give the button a style of *display:none* just in case the submit is cancelled—you don't want the button to appear.

Also need to check for the extra button in case it has already been added.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `name="submit"`. Because that just overwrites the form's `.submit()` method, since you can reference a form's field's (DOM Elements) via name. This was the cause of your problem. If you need to name the submit button, use another name besides those found under `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(document.forms[0])` list (these are all taken/reserved).

If your example was in the form of:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/test">
    <input type="text" name="inputname">
    <input type="submit" value="Send data" name="submitbutton">
</form>
```

Then you can submit your form using `formNode.submit()` as intended. You may reference the text box and submit button's DOM Element with `formNode.inputname` and `formNode.submitbutton`, respectively. Check with your console log to see this. :)

Comment: I don't have control over the form's contents. That's the problem. I need something that _always_ works -- having access to the submit method even if there is an attribute with that name would be fantastic.

Comment: I'm referring to the actual name used. If you name it something else. Then using `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit()` will submit that form as originally intended.

Comment: If you're trying to capture the value "Send data" from the form's POST request, then you will see that `submit="Send data"` already on the receiving end without attributing a `name` to the submit button.

Comment: I really, really, really do not have control over `<input type="submit" value="Send data" name="submit">`. I really, really cannot change the form itself.